# How to set proxy with authentication on selenium on ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy

I am currently using selenium and crawling a website.
I have tested if I could set a proxy server on Selenium.

But now, I want to set a paid rental proxy server and I got a trial IP address whose the format looks like this `IP:PORT:USER:PASS`.

And I don't know how to set USER:PASS.
The provider didn't know how to set in Selenium.

So I don't know what I can do now.

With random proxy this worked fine.

```
proxy_host = '185.186.61.44'
proxy_port = '11334'

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://#{proxy_host}:#{proxy_port}")
```

So I wanted to set something like this.

```
proxy_host = '185.186.61.44'
proxy_port = '12323'
proxy_user = "7a2345129"
proxy_pass = "easdga341d4"
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://#{proxy_host}:#{proxy_port}:#{proxy_user}:#{proxy_pass}")
```

but I found that it was not that easy as I read some solution that uses puppeteer.

I wonder if there are any solution for my case.

If anybody has any clues I would love you to tell me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 4 added support for [basic auth](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/0f0ffa0c9c968feb69266010aa60ec556d54c2e7/rb/CHANGES#L219), which at the time of writing is Chrome specific.
See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/64447d4b03f6986337d1ca8d8b6476653570bcc1/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/has_authentication.rb#L26) for more details.

To specify basic auth creds:

```
driver.devtools.new
driver.register(username: 'username', password: 'password')
```

Example using [scraperapi.com](https://www.scraperapi.com/) as proxy

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(
  http: 'proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
  ssl: 'proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001'
)
cap = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(proxy: proxy)
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--headless',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
    '--single-process',
    '--ignore-certificate-errors'
  ]
)

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, capabilities: [options,cap])
driver.devtools.new
driver.register(username: 'scraperapi', password: 'xxxx')

driver.navigate.to("http://httpbin.org/ip")
puts "content: #{driver.page_source}"
```

The `Chrome::Options` above are specific to my usecase, expect for the `ignore-certificate-errors` option which is needed to handle https traffic using scraperapi's proxies.

gemfile had:

```
gem 'selenium-devtools', '~> 0.91.0'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 4.1'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. After instlaling selenium-devtools I still get an error that driver.devtools and driver.register do not exist as methods.

Answer (score 0):

The format of an URL is most like

```
proto://USER:PASS@host.domain.tld:port
```

So your code have to look like :

```
proxy_host = '185.186.61.44' 
proxy_port = '12323'
proxy_user = "7a2345129"
proxy_pass = "easdga341d4"
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://{proxy_user}:#{proxy_pass}@#{proxy_host}:#{proxy_port}:#")
```

Comment: Thank you. But it was not working either. on curl, the URL you gave me worked fine. but in selenium it doesn't work.